# how can i parse http request body from tcp data

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I'm learning the windows network programing, now there is a problem,how can i http request body from tcp packet, this is the code:

```
    switch (ntohs(tcpHeader->destinationPort))
{
case 21:

    break;
case 80:
    decodeHttp(((char*)tcpHeader+sizeof(TCPHeader)),ipHeader->ipDestination);
    break;
}

void decodeHttp(char* pData,DWORD destIp){

in_addr addr = *(in_addr*)&destIp;
char ip[32];

strcpy_s(ip,inet_ntoa(addr));
printf(" %s \r\n",ip);
printf("--------------------------\r\n");
printf("%s ",pData);
```

if i just print "pData",there is only the http header,the body is messy code.

Comment: Are you using raw sockets? Why? Otherwise, you should never have to deal with TCP headers at the application level. If you want to parse HTTP, don't use raw sockets.

Comment: It looks like pData has successfully been indexed past the TCP header, so I don't understand the question.  Please add a copy of what pData prints and explain where to want to separate the HTTP header from the body.

Comment: yes,I am using a raw socket.i want to get the http response content.but i can't parse it from the data,if i just print it,there only the http header,the content is messy code.